# How do I remove a entire line which has contain javadoc comment?

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

How can I remove lines that only contain javadoc comment using Eclipse **Find/Replace prompt**.
I have following scenario,

```
/** The panel. */
private JPanel panel;
/** The text field. */
private JTextField textField1;
/** The text field_1. */
private JTextField textField2;
/** The button. */
private JButton button;
/** The combo box. */
private JComboBox comboBox;
```

Now I want to remove the entire line which contain **/****
What **regex** should I use in **eclipse** to **search and remove the lines** ?

Comment: What if the line is `/** comment */ private JCombobox comboBox;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\*\*.*\r?\n?
```

matches an entire line that starts with `/**` including (if present) any following newline characters.

```
/\*\*.*?\*/
```

matches a single comment.